# A Simple Matrix Product Returns NaN in R

Tags: r, matrix, product, nan

In R, I have a 3000x4 matrix that looks like the following:

```
  [1,]  8.458792e-02  6.915341e-02  2.179035e-01  8.458792e-02
   [2,]  1.933362e-01  2.895261e-01  2.836058e-01  1.933362e-01
   [3,]  2.706257e-02  3.233158e-02  7.077421e-02  2.706257e-02
   [4,]  2.621281e-01  1.448730e-01  5.983300e-01  2.621281e-01
   [5,]  2.018450e-01  2.322246e-01  1.634069e-01  0.000000e+00
   [6,]  2.990089e-01  4.956391e-01  3.123204e-01  2.990089e-01
   [7,]  1.244709e+00 -4.636184e-01  2.340081e+00  1.244709e+00
   [8,] -1.124598e+00 -1.761734e+00  2.832896e-01  0.000000e+00
   [9,]  1.394569e-02  2.337716e-02  3.243019e-02  1.394569e-02
  [10,] -2.134538e-01 -1.295015e-01  1.296246e-01  0.000000e+00
[ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 2990 rows ]
```

Here, let me call the matrix "C".

I am suffering from a problem that the matrix product returns NaNs:

```
> t(C)%*%C
NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

But, if I try to the calculation using only the first 100 rows, the problem does not occur:

```
>t(C[1:100,])%*%C[1:100,]
27.063320  8.051414 27.027122 15.340364
8.051414 10.571046  5.213047  3.521941
27.027122  5.213047 41.211831 23.785906
15.340364  3.521941 23.785906 15.340364
```

So, why does this happens? and how can I solve this problem?

(Of course, my code has more details but the only source where the problem happens is just the matrix product aforementioned, thus, I think additional detail may be not informative to solve this problem.)

Comment: This is surprising; the most parsimonious answer is that there is an `NaN` in your matrix somewhere. What is `summary(c(C))`?  `sum(!is.finite(C))` ? (By the way, `crossprod()` is a slightly more efficient way to do this calculation)

Comment: By using the ```summary``` function, I found four NAs. So, I think, I have to scrutinize the code again. Thank you for your help.